# django login screen (default setting) doesn't display properly?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-login

My django admin page didn't display properly. Like a pure html display. Can someone help here?

I don't have the permission to upload screenshot. But you can imagine, it doesn't look the same as tutorial shows.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have static files serving set up. If you have `DEBUG` turned on, you'll get this automatically with Django's development server (`./manage.py runserver`). If running in production, you need to set this up manually. See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Basically your static files are not set up properly, some of the reasons can be :-

1. If you running on a server like apache, you need to have static url in settings.py and same alias in httpd.conf file of apache.
2. If you are running on django in built server, please try to set Debug=True, which will force django to serve those static files.
3. If you have debug=False in settings.py file, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/
4. Because u really need a static files from django, sometimes you have to set the alias of django admin static files separately, which can be set in urls.py that is pointing to django package

Comment: I am using django built-in runserver, and I have DEBUG=TRUE setting

Comment: Within that html page and django logs please try to look where is the django application looking exactly for the css/js files.

Comment: I don't know the default path to the admin login page. this is what the url setup looks like
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # ...
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    # ...
)

Answer (score 0):

found the issue.

I forgot to turn on
'django.contrib.staticfiles'

in setting.py file